# Unauthorized error with oauth2-proxy´s allow-group flag

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, oauth2-proxy, quay.io

I am using oauth2 to handle the authentication/authorization via a company´s SSO provider of a web app running in k8.
The authentication works like a charm, however, once enable authorization for a specific group ( here: "ADMIN"), I always get a `403 - Forbidden "Invalid session: unauthorized"` error.

Version:
`quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:v7.3.0`

SSO Provider: `oidc`

My setup:

```
extraArgs:
  show-debug-on-error: True
  oidc-groups-claim: "ent_group"
  allowed-group: ["ADMIN"]
  oidc-email-claim: "email"
  scope: "openid ent_group"
  whitelist-domain: ...
  cookie-domain: ...
```

It matches the response from the SSO provider when tested with Postman:

```
{
    "email": "user@mail.com",
    "entitlement_group": [
        "ADMIN",
        "USER"
    ],
    "app_id": "app"
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Hm, shouldn't `ent_group` and `entitlement_group` actually match verbatim?

Comment: Bennimi are you able to resolve it?

Comment: yes, I used the ini file instead of the args.. and it works. Cba to figure what the problem was in the end.